# How to export signed application package in eclipse with proguard and crashlytics?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard, crashlytics

The crashlytics knowledge base says : "When building for release with Eclipse, export your application to an APK using the “Export Crashlytics-enabled Android Application” exporter from the Eclipse export menu."

But I couldn't find this option. Here's the [link](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202143-eclipse-and-proguard)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind I found it. It's in File-> Export and under the Android folder, there's a new "Export Crashlytics-enabled Android Application" option.

Had a habit of exporting the other way so never looked here before.

Comment: Hey, please help  me out ! What is the difference between "Export Crashlytics enabled android application" and the general "export android application"

Comment: @AbhinavArora It makes a difference if you're using Proguard (which you should). Check this [Crashlytics knowledge base link for more info.](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202143-eclipse-with-proguard).

Comment: Sir, I didn't really understand this. Please help me out. !! I dont really understood how this works. Can you please look at this question and answer it please - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687308/fabric-edits-the-project-properties

Comment: Are you using Proguard and Crashlytics? If not, don't worry about this question. Are you still using Eclipse? If not, don't worry about this question.

Comment: I am using crashlytics as well as eclipse. And I want to use pro guard too. But I am not understanding how to do it ? Because as mentioned in my question (link above). Fabric has removed the line - proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt    from the project.properties file and as far as I know it is required for proguard to run