# Do I have to export Crashlytics enabled android application?

Tags: android, crashlytics

Hello I am working on android app where I am using Crashlytics. I am releasing build on Play Store. I am not using Proguard for now.

Do I have to export Crashlytics enabled android application ? and what other settings I have to do before release to market for Crashlytics.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have using crashlytics too, but never find something tell me about these export **Crashlytics enabled android application**

but when im upload my apps in google play (using usually method without crashlytics enabled blablahh), my crashlytics apss working perfect, send me error report when it happen.

but, maybe you can check this link

[How to export signed application package in eclipse with proguard and crashlytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156701/how-to-export-signed-application-package-in-eclipse-with-proguard-and-crashlytic)

Comment: Yes that thread is using proguard but I am not using proguard

Comment: owh sorry, i forgot to tell you, i dont using proguard too :) just signed your apk and upload it into google play

Comment: You use simply "Export Android Application" or "Export Crashlytics-enabled Android Application" ?

Comment: Export Android Application