# Fabric edits the project.properties

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics, android-proguard

I have integrated Fabric in my app. When I open the project.properties file now, it says - **This file is now handled by Fabric**. Now I cannot see the following line anywhere in the **project.properties** file

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

I am using in app billing in my app and for that I need to add

```
-keep class com.android.vending.billing
```

in the **proguard-project.txt**

Now I am confused as - **project.properties** has no line mentioning the proguard-project.txt. So will it ever be used ? If not how and where should I add the line - -keep class com.android.vending.billing

Comment: i am having the same issue , i want to enable proguard but i did not get any hint on google

Comment: For those of who are facing the issue,  I e-mailed the fabric guys and they told me there must be some issue/bug. So use to original Fabric.properties file only